# React SplitButton data-test-id for options

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a SplitButton with several `options` and the options-properties `label` and `value`. I want to add a property like `data-test-id` to `options` to use them in my Cypress test.

But it's giving me an error of:

> TS2322: Type '{label: JSX.Elemetn; value:string; datatestid:string;}' is not assignable to type {label: ReactNode; value:string;}'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'datatestid' does not exist in type '{label: ReactNode; value:string}'.

How can I add a property like that to my SplitButton options?

Comment: can you write down your error in here, so that we can give some solution.

Comment: @PradipDhakal Okay I did :)

Comment: actually this one is a typescript error, so to get rid of it, you need to extend the default type which comes with JSX.Element and add your custom type so it will work.